# Are "commentable" and "categorizable" proper?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammaticality, adjectives

Can I say "commentable and categorizable"? If not, what are some one word alternatives to use, to say that something can be commented on or categorized?

I would like to use the words for database column names, so there is no actual context. But if you want I could use this sentence:

> The content is commentable and categorizable.

I just wanted to know if these words are acceptable terms or if I misunderstood something.

Comment: Please give some context.

Comment: English is not just a big bag of words; asking about the adjectives is useless without some kind of context. What kinds of things are involved? Who's doing the categorizing? Who's doing the comments? Who's permitting comments on it -- and what's _it_, by the way? You've left out way too many words already; why try to pin it down to only one? This is not the way to be clear. Less is not always better; **clear** is better.

Comment: See my edited question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Categorizable* is already in some dictionaries, so no problems there.

The problem with *commentable* is that what you really want to say is *comment-on-able*, but we can't use *-able* with phrasal verbs.

So here are your alternatives:

1. Just say *commentable* anyway.  If people understand what you mean, then there's no problem.
2. Say *comment-on-able*.
3. Find a one word synonym for *comment on*.　I can't think of an exact synonym, but there are plenty of words that might be suitable, depending on context: e.g. *discuss(able)*, *criticize (criticizable)*, *append(able)*, *annotate (annotatable)*, etc.

Which you choose is a matter of personal taste and context.  For example, if I was documenting computer software, and if the term *comment* was already widely used and understood, I would choose 1, because consistent terminology is more important than formal grammatical correctness.

Comment: Thank you. Perfect answer for my needs, especially with that note for software purposes. But if use Nr.1 in a normal conversation apart software-design it would sound worse, is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 3):

If you follow the C++ practice of creating adjectives from verbs by tacking on the adjective suffix [*-able/-ible*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-able) to create such words as

*copyable*, *assignable*, *constructible*, *comparable*, not to mention *CopyAssignable* and *CopyConstructible*

and you use *commentable* and *categorizable* in a similar context, people will have no trouble understanding what you mean.

If, however, you're writing in a context where the Grammar Police might jump on you, *[annotatable](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/annotatable)* and *[classifiable](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/classifiable)* are sanctioned alternatives.

Comment: +1 for mentioning C++ practice , you make me smile. Although it will be better if you use C instead of C++, because these practices origin from C.

Comment: @speedyGonzales Interesting; I only became aware of the terms when I learned about the Standard Library and its requirement that objects put into containers be _copyable_ and _assignable_...

Comment: @ Gnawme Well it seems it was unsuccessful attempt for a joke concerning C for the chicken and C++ for the egg. In my Advanced OOP classes, I remember that we have implemented almost all possible suffix algorithms. And I have passed them in Java. Is the language so important to you ?

Comment: @speedyGonzales "Is the language so important to you?" The English language, yes; the programming language, not so much. (Although I have many, many years invested in C++...)